# How to drag element with data attribute and drop it in the box which has the same id

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I have three list item, each one with specific data attribute and different color. I have to drag and drop each one of them in box which has the same id and border color  as dragging item. 
Here is example
http://jsbin.com/xobekewo/3/edit.

Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were on the right track. In `accept` function you can access the droppable element via `this` and the draggable element is passed in as the first argument. You can compare those 2 and return wether this droppable should accept the draggable in question. For example:

```
accept: function Accept(el) {
  if (el.hasClass("draggable") && (el.attr("data"))) {
    // accept this draggable element if the data attribute
    // matches the id of the droppable element
    return $(this).attr('id') === el.attr("data");
  }
}
```

Or a full code snippet in your case

```
$(function() {
  $(".draggable").draggable({
    revert: "invalid"
  });
  $(".divel").droppable({
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    accept: function Accept(el) {
      if (el.hasClass("draggable") && (el.attr("data"))) {
        return $(this).attr('id') === el.attr("data");
     }
   }
 });
```

});

Here's your original fiddle modified

http://jsbin.com/xobekewo/10/edit

Some other remarks

1. You should be using data atrributes instead of just the data attribute, for example instead of `<div data="div1">` you should do something like `<div data-droppable-id="div1">` and then access it via `$("div").data("droppable-id")`.
2. I've added CSS `.draggable {display: inline-block}` - otherwise they have the width of the entire page and interfere with each other when being dragged/dropped, because they overlay each other.

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you very much not only for decision on for advice too. Аppreciate it